# Format a JavaScript string using placeholders and an object of substitutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, string-formatting

I have a string with say: `My Name is %NAME% and my age is %AGE%.`

`%XXX%` are placeholders. We need to substitute values there from an object.

Object looks like: `{"%NAME%":"Mike","%AGE%":"26","%EVENT%":"20"}`

I need to parse the object and replace the string with corresponding values. So that final output will be:

> My Name is Mike and my age is 26.

The whole thing has to be done either using pure javascript or jquery.

Comment: That looks more like an object than an array

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the string [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method? (Also, you don't have an array there, you have an object.)

Comment: That's pretty ugly. Surely you'd be just as well served by `{NAME: "Mike", AGE: 26, EVENT: 20}`? You'd still require that these keys appear bookended by percent signs in the input string, of course.

Comment: it seems I am too late to answer, but npm pupa library is quite handy if you want to fill values dynamically and easily. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pupa

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The requirements of the original question clearly couldn't benefit from string interpolation, as it seems like it's a runtime processing of arbitrary replacement keys.

*However*, if you just had to do string interpolation, you can use:

```
const str = `My name is ${replacements.name} and my age is ${replacements.age}.`
```

**Note the backticks delimiting the string, they are required.**

---

For an answer suiting the particular OP's requirement, you could use `String.prototype.replace()` for the replacements.

The following code will handle all matches and not touch ones without a replacement (so long as your replacement values are all strings, if not, see below).

```
var replacements = {"%NAME%":"Mike","%AGE%":"26","%EVENT%":"20"},
    str = 'My Name is %NAME% and my age is %AGE%.';

str = str.replace(/%\w+%/g, function(all) {
   return replacements[all] || all;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/pMb9S/).

If some of your replacements are not strings, be sure they exists in the object first. If you have a format like the example, i.e. wrapped in percentage signs, you can use the `in` operator to achieve this.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/376w3abx/).

However, if your format doesn't have a special format, i.e. any string, and your replacements object doesn't have a `null` prototype, use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`, unless you can guarantee that none of your potential replaced substrings will clash with property names on the prototype.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aahm85r/).

Otherwise, if your replacement string was `'hasOwnProperty'`, you would get a resultant messed up string.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vktkh6jj/).

---

As a side note, you should be called `replacements` an `Object`, not an `Array`.

Comment: +1. Nice. Though you might want to say `return replacements[all] || all` to cover `%NotInReplacementsList%` cases.

Comment: This will not work if the replacement value is falseish. So it's better to use this return statement: `return all in params ? params[all] : all;`

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Shouldn't your replacements all be strings? If you want to replace with empty string, better off checking with other means.

Comment: @alex I had the situation where replacements could also be integers, and even `0`. In this case it didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Updated to cover that case.

Comment: Awesome, simple solution, I use it with different pattern  /\[\[\w+\]\]/g

Comment: With arrow function: 
`str.replace(/%\w+%/g, placeholder => replacements[placeholder] || placeholder);`

Answer (score 32):

How about using ES6 template literals?

```
var a = "cat";
var b = "fat";
console.log(`my ${a} is ${b}`); //notice back-ticked string
```

[More about template literals...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: If you have an object with placeholders like the OP, how does string interpolation help that?

Comment: Works like a charm! Most pragmatic solution to my placeholding problems, perfect.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for runtime replacements

Answer (score 30):

Currently there is still no native solution in Javascript for this behavior. [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are something related, but don't solve it.

Here there is a refactor of [alex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975025/7713952) with an object for replacements.

The solution uses **arrow functions** and a similar **syntax for the placeholders** as the native Javascript [interpolation in template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`{}` instead of `%%`). Also there is **no need to include delimiters** (`%`) in the names of the replacements.

There are two flavors (three with the update): descriptive, reduced, elegant reduced with groups.

**Descriptive solution:**

```js
const stringWithPlaceholders = 'My Name is {name} and my age is {age}.';

const replacements = {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: '26',
};

const string = stringWithPlaceholders.replace(
  /{\w+}/g,
  placeholderWithDelimiters => {
    const placeholderWithoutDelimiters = placeholderWithDelimiters.substring(
      1,
      placeholderWithDelimiters.length - 1,
    );
    const stringReplacement = replacements[placeholderWithoutDelimiters] || placeholderWithDelimiters;
    return stringReplacement;
  },
);

console.log(string);
```

**Reduced solution:**

```js
const stringWithPlaceholders = 'My Name is {name} and my age is {age}.';

const replacements = {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: '26',
};

const string = stringWithPlaceholders.replace(/{\w+}/g, placeholder =>
  replacements[placeholder.substring(1, placeholder.length - 1)] || placeholder
);

console.log(string);
```

### UPDATE 2020-12-10

**Elegant reduced solution with groups, as suggested by [@Kade in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975005/format-a-javascript-string-using-placeholders-and-an-object-of-substitutions/61634647#comment114559321_61634647):**

```js
const stringWithPlaceholders = 'My Name is {name} and my age is {age}.';

const replacements = {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: '26',
};

const string = stringWithPlaceholders.replace(
  /{(\w+)}/g, 
  (placeholderWithDelimiters, placeholderWithoutDelimiters) =>
    replacements[placeholderWithoutDelimiters] || placeholderWithDelimiters
);

console.log(string);
```

### UPDATE 2021-01-21

**Support empty string as a replacement, as suggested by [@Jesper in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975005/format-a-javascript-string-using-placeholders-and-an-object-of-substitutions/61634647#comment116373135_61634647):**

```js
const stringWithPlaceholders = 'My Name is {name} and my age is {age}.';

const replacements = {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: '',
};

const string = stringWithPlaceholders.replace(
  /{(\w+)}/g, 
  (placeholderWithDelimiters, placeholderWithoutDelimiters) =>
  replacements.hasOwnProperty(placeholderWithoutDelimiters) ? 
    replacements[placeholderWithoutDelimiters] : placeholderWithDelimiters
);

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's great to have a generic solution for a placeholder string and an object to merge into it like this

Comment: @CarlosP, that's the idea, to have a generic solution. But I think it should be something native to the language, as it's a common use case.

Comment: This can be simplified a bit more by using regex groups like this: `stringWithPlaceholders.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, (fullMatch, group1) => replacements[group1] || fullMatch )`

Comment: All these solutions suffer from the bug of using "||", since the empty string is also falsy in Javascript. This means that if a replacement string is empty, the placeholder will not be replaced. And it's absolutely valid for a replacement string to be empty. Instead of e.g. `replacements[group1] || fullMatch`, use `replacements.hasOwnProperty(group1) ? replacements[group1] : fullMatch`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use JQuery(jquery.validate.js) to make it work easily.

```
$.validator.format("My name is {0}, I'm {1} years old",["Bob","23"]);
```

Or if you want to use just that feature you can define that function and just use it like

```
function format(source, params) {
    $.each(params,function (i, n) {
        source = source.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "g"), n);
    })
    return source;
}
alert(format("{0} is a {1}", ["Michael", "Guy"]));
```

credit to jquery.validate.js team

Comment: You definitely wouldn't want to load this plugin just for this, but I'm already using this to validate a form on the page...so thanks for the tip!

Comment: Pretty inefficient to create a regex for each number, it would be better to match all numbers and then replace on if the value was found in the array, perhaps?

Comment: for those interested, it happens here:

https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L215-L239

Comment: + very nice ... and for `$.each` you could make `String.prototype.format=function(p){var s=this,r=function(v,i){s=s.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}","g"),v);};p.forEach(r);return s;}` so you don't have to include jquery just for that one ;)

Answer (score 13):

As with modern browser, placeholder is supported by new version of Chrome / Firefox, similar as the C style function `printf()`.

**Placeholders:**

- `%s` String.
- `%d`,`%i` Integer number.
- `%f` Floating point number.
- `%o` Object hyperlink.

**e.g.**

```
console.log("generation 0:\t%f, %f, %f", a1a1, a1a2, a2a2);
```

BTW, **to see the output:**

- In Chrome, use shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + J` or `F12` to open developer tool.
- In Firefox, use shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + K` or `F12` to open developer tool.

---

**@Update - nodejs support**

Seems nodejs don't support `%f`, instead, could use `%d` in nodejs.
With `%d` number will be printed as floating number, not just integer.

Comment: Man, can you pls include a reference link in your answer? 

Comment: @Amio.io You mean something like this? https://www.stravid.com/en/improve-your-javascript-console-log-friendship/

Comment: My bad, I thought it's from an official specification. Thx for the reference!

Comment: What if I don't want to just log the string, but keep it as value to do something else with it?

Comment: Node.js [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilformatformat-args) supports %f.

Answer (score 10):

Just use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var values = {"%NAME%":"Mike","%AGE%":"26","%EVENT%":"20"};
var substitutedString = "My Name is %NAME% and my age is %AGE%.".replace("%NAME%", $values["%NAME%"]).replace("%AGE%", $values["%AGE%"]);
```

Comment: obligatory "please use MDN as a reference": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Thanks for the spanking guys - appreciated ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a custom replace function like this:

```
var str = "My Name is %NAME% and my age is %AGE%.";
var replaceData = {"%NAME%":"Mike","%AGE%":"26","%EVENT%":"20"};

function substitute(str, data) {
    var output = str.replace(/%[^%]+%/g, function(match) {
        if (match in data) {
            return(data[match]);
        } else {
            return("");
        }
    });
    return(output);
}

var output = substitute(str, replaceData);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DyCwk/.

Comment: Cool, Alex did pretty much exactly the same thing but in fewer lines of code (though ternary operators are likely slower than if..else).

Comment: Hey, I gave you a +1! You both did a replace function, yours isn't exactly the same but pretty similar. Your RegExp is different too, the OP would be better off using %% or $$ or similar as delimiters - a single % or % is likely to occur in a string normally, but doubles are unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

This allows you to do exactly that

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject

GitHub: https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stringinject

By doing the following:

```
var str = stringInject("My username is {username} on {platform}", { username: "tjcafferkey", platform: "GitHub" });

// My username is tjcafferkey on Git
```

Comment: But since you can do it in es6 that is probably a bit overkill?

Comment: This lets you store the string in one place in one format and then at a later time replace the corresponding items using only one function. That is to my knowledge not possible to do with es6 template literals. A usage for this would e.g. be translation strings where you will consume the string elsewhere and inject the desired values there.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution if you're using node.js is StackExchange's own `formatUnicorn` utility function (https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-unicorn):

```
let x = {name:'jason', food:'pine cones'};
let s = '{name} enjoys a delicious bowl of {food}';

let formatted = x.formatUnicorn(s);
```

Also, a bit of an edge case, but if you aren't using Node but you *do* just happen to be writing a userscript for SE sites, then `formatUnicorn` will already be on the String prototype.

Comment: Note some [incorrect behavior](https://github.com/tallesl/node-format-unicorn/issues/2) depending on what's being replaced. Seems to be abandonware.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something closer to console.log like replacing %s placeholders like in

```
>console.log("Hello %s how are you %s is everything %s?", "Loreto", "today", "allright")
>Hello Loreto how are you today is everything allright?
```

I wrote this

```js
function log() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var rep= args.slice(1, args.length);
  var i=0;
  var output = args[0].replace(/%s/g, function(match,idx) {
    var subst=rep.slice(i, ++i);
    return( subst );
  });
   return(output);
}
res=log("Hello %s how are you %s is everything %s?", "Loreto", "today", "allright");
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML=res;
```

```html
<span id="console"/>
```

you will get

```
>log("Hello %s how are you %s is everything %s?", "Loreto", "today", "allright")
>"Hello Loreto how are you today is everything allright?"
```

**UPDATE**

I have added a simple variant as `String.prototype` useful when dealing with string transformations, here is it:

```
String.prototype.log = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var rep= args.slice(0, args.length);
    var i=0;
    var output = this.replace(/%s|%d|%f|%@/g, function(match,idx) {
      var subst=rep.slice(i, ++i);
      return( subst );
    });
    return output;
   }
```

In that case you will do

```
"Hello %s how are you %s is everything %s?".log("Loreto", "today", "allright")
"Hello Loreto how are you today is everything allright?"
```

Try this version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pr6u57L1/)

Comment: i made a variation on your function without prototypes
`formatMessage(message: string, values: string[]) {
    let i = 0;
    return message.replace(/%\w+%/g, (match, idx) => {
      return values[i++];
    });
  }`

this takes message to format and array of replace values and looks for `%SOME_VALUE%`

Answer (score 3):

> I have written a code that lets you format string easily.

#### Use this function.

```
function format() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        throw "No arguments";
    }
    const string = arguments[0];
    const lst = string.split("{}");
    if (lst.length !== arguments.length) {
        throw "Placeholder format mismatched";
    }
    let string2 = "";
    let off = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        if (off < arguments.length) {
            string2 += lst[i] + arguments[off++]
        } else {
            string2 += lst[i]
        }
    }
    return string2;
}
```

#### Example

```
format('My Name is {} and my age is {}', 'Mike', 26);
```

#### Output

> My Name is Mike and my age is 26

Answer (score 2):

ES6:

```js
const strFormat = (str, ...args) => args.reduce((s, v) => s.replace('%s', v), str);

// Use it like:
const result = strFormat('%s is %s yrs old', 'name', 23);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

As a quick example:

```
var name = 'jack';
var age = 40;
console.log('%s is %d yrs old',name,age);
```

The output is:

> jack is 40 yrs old

Comment: That's great, unless you want to do something besides log it to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this by using es6 template literals dynamically at runtime.

```js
const str = 'My name is ${name} and my age is ${age}.'
const obj = {name:'Simon', age:'33'}


const result = new Function('const {' + Object.keys(obj).join(',') + '} = this.obj;return `' + str + '`').call({obj})

document.body.innerHTML = result
```

Comment: Holy injection attack vulnerability, Batman!  Requires sanitizing `str` for backticks.

Answer (score 1):

```
const stringInject = (str = '', obj = {}) => {
  let newStr = str;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    let placeHolder = `#${key}#`;
    if(newStr.includes(placeHolder)) {
      newStr = newStr.replace(placeHolder, obj[key] || " ");
    }
  });
  return newStr;
}
```

```
Input: stringInject("Hi #name#, How are you?", {name: "Ram"});
Output: "Hi Ram, How are you?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good/similar answers here. I wanted the ability to easily get a nested key in an object (or perhaps some JSON data structure) for substitution, so I took the following simple approach:

```js
const getKey = (d, path) => {
  // path can be a string like 'key1.key2' or an iterable of keys
  if (typeof(path) === 'string') {
    path = path.split('.')
  }
  return path.reduce((x, y) => x[y], d)
}

const inject = (str, obj) => str.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g, (x,g)=> getKey(obj, g));


// Example

> const str = 'there are ${a} ways to ${b.c}'
undefined
> inject(str, {'a':'many', 'b': {'c': 'skin a cat'}})
'there are many ways to skin a cat'
```

Some inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594573/10682164) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782539/10682164).

Answer (score 0):

This is a merged solution of Gerson Diniz and Shubham Vyas.

It is possible to pass a set of arguments or an object.

```js
function strSwap(str) {

  if (!str) return null;
  
  let args = [];
  for (let a of arguments) 
    args.push(a);
  args.shift();
  
  if (!args.length) return null;
  
  // replacement by object - {{prop}}
  if (!!(args[0].constructor && args[0].constructor.name.toLowerCase() === 'object')) {
    for (let i in args[0]) {
      let n = `{{${i}}}`;
      str = str.includes(n) ? str.replaceAll(n, args[0][i] + '') : str;
    }
  }
  // replacement by placeholders - %s
  else {
    str = args.reduce((s, v) => s.replace('%s', v), str);
  }
  
  return str;

}

// ---------------------

console.log(strSwap('Hello %s, my name is %s.', 'alice', 'bob'));

console.log(strSwap('Hello {{a}}, my name is {{b}}. Hello {{b}}.', {
  a: 'alice', 
  b: 'bob'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex's code rock! Thanks!

Small modification to replacement function to be able to use the replacement variables by name directly.

```
var replacements = {
    "NAME": "Mike",
    "AGE": "26",
    "EVENT": "20"
},    
str = 'My Name is ${NAME} and my age is ${AGE}, the following ${placeholder} is missing.';

str = str.replace(/\$\{(.*?)\}/g, function(placeholder, name) {
    return replacements[name] || placeholder;
});
```