# Why is the variable not updating within a for loop? JS

Tags: javascript, template-literals

The for loop seems to run fine but fails to update the *element* variable.
My intention was:

```
<h6>Q1</h6>
<h6>Q2</h6>
<h6>Q3</h6>
```

Instead, the actual result was:

```
<h6>Q1</h6>
<h6>Q1</h6>
<h6>Q1</h6>
```

```js
  function results () {

     var listResults = '';
     var i=0;
     const element = `
      <h6>Q${i+1}</h6>
     `;

     for(x=0; x < 3; x++) {
        listResults += element;
        i++;
     }
     return listResults;
    }
    console.log(results())
```

Comment: Because at the moment the template literal is evaluated `i` has to the value `0`. If you want to get different result you have to define the template literal inside the loop.

Comment: You probably want to move `const element = …` inside the for loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused

Answer (score 1):

A few issues. Mainly, when `element` is evaluated `i` is `0` so `element` always returns `<h6>Q1</h6>`.

You can append the template literal directly to the output like this:

```js
function results () {

 var listResults = '';

 for(x=0; x < 3; x++) {
  listResults += `<h6>Q${x+1}</h6>\n`;
 }
 return listResults;
}
console.log(results())
```

Comment: I thought it wasn't wise to declare variables within a loop.

Comment: It's not. Another unwise thing is reassigning a `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The template is evaluated as soon as the expression is parsed. Something like this could work:

```js
let listResults = [];
const element = i => `<h6>Q${i+1}</h6>`;

for(x=0; x < 3; x++) {
    listResults += element(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `element` is assigned once, when `i` is equal to `0`. It never gets updated beyond that (despite `i` incrementing with each loop).

Furthermore, using a more modern method like `.map` yields a much more readable version of your outcome:

```js
const results = () => [1, 2, 3]
    .map(i => `
        <h6>Q${i}</h6>
    `)
    .join('');

console.log(results());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this problem only because you are declaring i variable every time you revoke function , and actually every time you are setting it to 0 and continuing .
so, the "i" variable must be declared out of(and before declaring) function (not in it)
and every time you invoke function, it's value will be added by one.

```
var i=0;
function results () {

     var listResults = '';
     const element = `
      <h6>Q${i+1}</h6>
     `;

     for(x=0; x < 3; x++) {
        listResults += element;
        i++;
     }
     return listResults;
    }
console.log(results())
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ES6:

```
const results = _ => Array.from({length:3}, i => `<h6>Q${i+1}</h6>`).join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using eval:

```js
var element = "<h6>Q${i}</h6>";

var results = [1, 2, 3].map(function (i) {
  return eval('`'+element+'`');
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: There is no need to use `eval` in this scenario. Please do not promote the use of `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use For OF instead of For LOOP :

```
for (let variable of iterable) {
// code block to be executed 
}
```

It lets you loop over iterable data structures such as Arrays, Strings, Maps, NodeLists, and more

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).