# Can you use template strings as an object value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Is there a way to create a hash of template strings?

Something like:

```
const myStrings = {
   a: `myStringA${test}`,
   b: `myStringB${test}`
}
```

And then somewhere else, you can do something like: `getString(index, test)`, and it can index into the object. I know that the above is wrong, but just wanted to give an example of what I have in mind. For instance, `getString(a, "Cat")` would return: `myStringACat`

Comment: https://media1.tenor.com/images/ca5edc01f8dcb0f01200a0b299036518/tenor.gif

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case I would see the following:

```js
var myStrings = {
    a: "myStringA${test}",
    b: "Name: ${name}, Id: ${id}",
 
    getString: function(index, o) {
      var string = this[index];

      Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
        if (string.indexOf("${" + key + "}")) {
       string = string.replace("${" + key + "}", o[key]);
        }
      });

      return string;
    },
};

console.log(
  myStrings.getString("a", {test: "Cat"}),
  " ",
  myStrings.getString("b", {name: "Arber", id: 123})
);

// "myStringACat"
// "Name: Arber, Id: 123"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, thank you!