# How to make each <i> element responsive to it's parent input created on 'keypress'

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a To-Do List in Vanilla Javascript and I want to make it create a new input every time someone presses return on the previous one, which for now is working. I also want to append a checkmark to it, so whenever the task has been finished you can click on it, and it will change the background-color of the input next to which the checkmark is. The only problem is I don't know how to assign some kind of value to each checkmark so the eventListener doesn't always get the first ID selected.

Tried assigning a value to each checkmark and put it into an array, but do not know how to actually assign the exact same value of each checkmark into the array.

```js
let counter, checkmark, cross, list, newRow, addInput, addCheckmark, listid, wrapper, current1;

counter = 1;
checkmark = document.getElementById('checkmark');
cross = document.getElementById('cross');
wrapper = document.querySelector('.to-do-wrapper');
current1 = document.getElementById('current1');

let values = [];

// Event Delegation to listen to all target.matches :)
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (event.target.matches('.input-new-list')) {
    let randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    list = document.querySelector('.list');
    newRow = document.createElement("li");
    addInput = document.createElement('input');
    addCheckmark = document.createElement('i');
    addCheckmark.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-check');
    addInput.setAttribute('id', 'current-' + counter)
    addInput.setAttribute('class', 'input-new-list');
    addInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newRow.setAttribute('class', 'new-list');
    let key = e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) {
      list.appendChild(newRow);
      newRow.appendChild(addCheckmark);
      addCheckmark.setAttribute('id', 'checkmark');
      /* addCheckmark.setAttribute('value', randomVal);
      values.push(randomVal); */
      newRow.appendChild(addInput);
      document.getElementById('current-' + counter).focus();
      counter++;
      document.querySelector('#default').removeAttribute('placeholder');
    }
  }
});

// Show edit buttons on click edit list
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  list = document.querySelector('.list');
  newRow = document.createElement("li");
  addInput = document.createElement('input');
  addCheckmark = document.createElement('i');
  // Ad a random value to checkmark -> Push into array. If event.target.matches checkmark value => execute if
  if (event.target.matches('#checkmark')) {
    // On click of checkmark, change input background and toggle checkmark color
    if (event.target.classList !== 'active') {
      checkmark.classList.toggle('active');
      if (document.querySelector('.input-new-list')) {
        document.querySelector('.input-new-list').classList.toggle('checked');
      } else if (document.querySelector('current' + counter)) {
        document.querySelector('#current' + counter).classList.toggle('checked')
      }
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  if (event.target.matches('input')) {
    cross.classList.add('active');
  } else if (!event.target.matches('input')) {
    cross.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid to-do-wrapper" id="toDo">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="new-list">
      <i class="fas fa-check" id="checkmark"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Create a new list" class="input-new-list" id="default" />
      <i class="fas fa-times" id="cross"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just looking for a way to assign each checkmark and input to its parent `li`, so doing something on it, wouldn't affect the first selected element but the one being edited.

Comment: when you add the new input, don't just create it alone, add a checkbox next to it then add them both

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1):

You can 'assign value' to checkmark by add/remove class. Don't use same `id` for many elements. Try to change approach and separate view and data using [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) as [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594573/860099)

```js
let list= [{text:'', done: false}]; // data

function show() {
  toDo.innerHTML = list.map((x,i)=> inject(item.innerHTML,{
    check: x.done ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-uncheck',
    done: x.done ? 'done' : '',
    hide: i ? '' : 'hide',
    text: x.text,
    i,
  })).join('');
}

function inject(str, obj) { return str.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g, (x,g)=> obj[g]) }

function check(i) { list[i].done = !list[i].done; show(); }

function change(inp,i) { list[i].text = inp.value; }

function del(i) { list.splice(i,1); show(); }

function newItem(i) {
  list.splice(i+1,0,{text:'',done: false});
  show();
  this['inp'+(i+1)].focus();
}

show();
```

```css
ul{ list-style-type: none; }
.fas { cursor: pointer }
.done { background: #dfd }
.input-new-list {margin: 5px}
.fa-check::after { content: '[+]'}
.fa-uncheck::after { content: '[-]'}
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
Click on left '[-]' to mark task as done, type enter to add new, click 'x' to delete

<div class="container-fluid to-do-wrapper">
  <ul class="list" id="toDo"></ul>
</div>

<template id="item">
  <li class="new-list">
    <i class="fas ${check}" 
       onclick="check(${i})"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Create a new list"
           class="input-new-list ${done}" 
           value="${text}" id="inp${i}"
           onchange="newItem(${i})" 
           oninput="change(this, ${i})"/>
    <i class="fas fa-times ${hide}" onclick="del(${i})">x</i>
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Damn! Thanks for the detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I kind of went a different direction, storing the data as information in the DOM, and providing a function to generate a JS object that represents todo list data on demand. I used Kamil's CSS in my answer, with some slight changes.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul.list');

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  const eventTarget = e.target;

  if (e.keyCode === 13 && eventTarget.parentElement && eventTarget.parentElement.classList.contains('new-item')) {
    const clonedListItem = eventTarget.parentElement.cloneNode(true);

    clonedListItem.classList.remove('new-item');

    const icons = clonedListItem.querySelectorAll('i');

    icons.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('hidden'));

    const [doneIcon, deleteIcon] = icons;

    doneIcon.addEventListener('click', () => toggleDone(clonedListItem));
    deleteIcon.addEventListener('click', () => deleteItem(clonedListItem));

    list.insertBefore(clonedListItem, eventTarget.parentElement);

    eventTarget.removeAttribute('placeholder');
    eventTarget.value = '';
  }
});

document.getElementById('generateJSON').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const data = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.list li')]
    .filter(li => !li.classList.contains('new-item'))
    .map(li => ({
      text: li.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value,
      done: li.classList.contains('done')
    }));

  console.log('data', data);
});

function toggleDone(item) {
  item.classList.toggle('done');
}

function deleteItem(item) {
  item.remove();
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.fas {
  cursor: pointer
}

li.done input[type="text"] {
  background: #dfd
}

.input-new-list {
  margin: 5px
}

li i.fa-check::after {
  content: '[+]'
}

li.done i.fa-check::after {
  content: '[-]'
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="new-item">
    <i class="fas fa-check hidden"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Create a new list" />
    <i class="fas hidden" id="cross">x</i>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="generateJSON" value="Generate JSON" />
```