# Render javascript file with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object, ecmascript-6

I am having the following `*.js` file:

```
var text = `
This is a test ${Company.Name}.
`

module.exports = {
    text
};
```

My main file looks like the following:

```
const Company = {}
Company.Name = "Apple"
```

Basically, I would like to "render" the text and fill it with my predefined variable.

Any suggestions what is the best way to "load" the text file in the main file?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Better to export `Company.Name` from `*.js` file.

Comment: Given that `Company.Name` is "nothing" in your js file, why not export a function? (e.g. ```module.exports = Company => `This is a test ${Company.name}```) Because right now the code you're showing doesn't really make any sense, modules are supposed to be self contained: anything they need, you either require in the module, it it's specified at call time. There is no "relying on magical global values".

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  How would you structure the code differently?

Comment: @Anna.Klee: The comment mentions a function – if you export the function ``text: Company => `This is a test ${Company.name}`,`` instead of a direct literal ``text: `This is a test ${Company.name}`,``, you can call the function from the other file and get the string you want back. That’s probably the least awkward way to accomplish it, if possible. (Also rahamanabdurar’s answer.)

Comment: I'd either export a function (I showed a  "fat arrow" function but you can also use a normal one: ```module.exports = function(company) { return `text blah ${company.someval}`;}``` but really, what you're showing is code that belongs in your `Company` class, so you can call `Company.getNamedString()` or whatever feels the most appropriate name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *.js file

```
var text = (Company)=> `This is a test ${Company.Name}.`

module.exports = {
    text
};
```

in main.js file

```
let { text }  = require('./hello');

const Company = {}
Company.Name = "Apple"

let try = text(Company);
console.log(try):
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import it:

```
const { text } = require("./*");
```

Comment: Do you mean `require` instead of `import`? That won’t work, since `const Company` isn’t a global.

Comment: @Ry- I din't quite understand what you mean here ,please could you explain further?