# How to use HTML <template> with variables (with Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html5-template

Currently I'm doing the following:

**This is my HTML template**

```xml
<template id="catDisplayTemplate">
      <div class="col">
        <img class="mehow" src="{{catImg}}" alt="" data-name="{{catName}}" data-id="{{catId}}">
        <div class="row space-between">
          <div class="col">
            <p class="description">{{catDescription}}</p>
          </div>
       </div>
       </div>
</template>
```

**The following code change the moustaches but it feels like repeating itself**

```
const catTemplate = document.querySelector('#catDisplayTemplate').innerHTML;
catTemplate = catTemplate.replace(/{{catImg}}/g, catData.img);
catTemplate = catTemplate.replace(/{{catName}}/g, catData.name);
catTemplate = catTemplate.replace(/{{catId}}/g, catData.id);
catTemplate = catTemplate.replace(/{{catDescription}}/g, catData.description);
```

*catData is the object with the details.

**Is there a better/other way?**

Comment: Are you considering using some template library? For example, lodash.template or handlebar?

Comment: I think cloning the node and using querySelector to set attributes/properties is cleaner https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: `handlebarsjs` and `mustachejs` already exists that do this sort of logic.  Since you are asking how to make something, better, this looks like a refactoring question, rather than a problem question, and appears to be off topic for the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can ES6 template literals be substituted at runtime (or reused)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused)

Comment: Good ideas in the comments -thanks. I ended up leaving it as is. Since the focus of this project was for practicing MVC.

Comment: Your code could be simplified a lot: for instance, there's no need to repeat _catTemplate.replace_ every time.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an interpolate function that accepts the template and an object containing the keys and values you want to replace. There are several examples in the answer to this question: [Can ES6 template literals be substituted at runtime (or reused)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused)

Here is one that I use, which I borrowed from [here](https://medium.com/@mrg101/this-is-great-thinking-2153c8982152):  It sanitizes input against XSS attack and replaces placeholders with variables. I am likely to split this into separate functions for production use.

```
interpolate(template, params) {
    const replaceTags = { '&': '&amp;', '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '(': '%28', ')': '%29' };
    const safeInnerHTML = text => text.toString().replace(/[&<>\(\)]/g, tag => replaceTags[tag] || tag);
    const keys = Object.keys(params);
    const keyVals = Object.values(params).map(safeInnerHTML);
    return new Function(...keys, `return \`${template}\``)(...keyVals);
 }
```

You would use it like this:

```
const template = document.querySelector('myTemplate')
const data = { name: 'John Doe', age: 25}    
someDiv.innerHTML = interpolate(template.innerHTML.toString().trim(), data)
```