# Manipulate CQL params from database in javascript

Tags: javascript

I store CQL filtering params as varchar in the database which i have to manipulate in JavaScript. `street_desc` is a variable in javascript. How can i assign it to the string dynamically?

Whatever is inside the `input_params` has to replace the cql_param string

```
var street_desc= "whatever"; //input from the user
var town_code = "whatever2"; //input from the user
var cql_param= "roadname_gr='street_desc'&towndesc is not null&town_code='town_code'"; //comes from database

var input_params = [street_desc,town_code]; //declare input params to replace the cql string
```

The output should be:

`"roadname_gr='whatever'&towndesc is not null&town_code='whatever2'";`

What i have tried...

```
var street_desc = "whatever"; //input from the user
var town_code = "whatever2"; //input from the user
var cql_param = "roadname_gr='street_desc'&towndesc is not null&town_code='town_code'"; //comes from database

var input_params = {
    street_desc: street_desc,
    town_code: town_code
}; //declare input params to replace the cql string



for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input_params)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    cql_param.replace(key, value);
}
```

Comment: replace the placeholder?

Comment: It has to be dynamic, not hard-coded. For example I can have an array of input_params. I will update my question

Comment: check my update

Comment: to me this still looks like you want to do a string replace. simply use an array with key-value-pairs: `{ placeholder: 'street_deesc', value: 'whatever' }`

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Here is what i did:
Declare an object with my input params i want to replace. Iterate over the key-value pairs and replace the string.

```js
var street_desc_inp = "whatever"; //input from the user
var town_code_inp = "whatever2"; //input from the user
var cql_param = "roadname_gr='street_desc_inp'&towndesc is not null&town_code='town_code_inp'"; //comes from database

console.log(cql_param)

var input_params = { //declare input params to replace the cql string
street_desc_inp: street_desc_inp,
town_code_inp: town_code_inp
};


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input_params))
cql_param = cql_param.replace(key, value);


console.log(cql_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

I update my answer to use a reducer

```js
let cql_param= "roadname_gr='street_desc'&towndesc is not null&town_code=1"; 
var street_desc= "whatever"; //input from the user
var town_code = "whatever2"; //input from the user

var input_params = [street_desc,town_code]; 
var input_params_names = ["street_desc","1"]; 
let i =0;
const result = input_params.reduce((ac,c)=>{
  return ac.replace(input_params_names[i++], c);
},cql_param)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: have you tried it I update its  my code its not missing now

Comment: output is still incorrect. It should be `"roadname_gr='whatever'&towndesc is not null&town_code='whatever2'";`

Comment: are these the only values you want to replace or are there more meaning some other cases you didn't include ?

Comment: these are just examples, now it seems correct. But i believe it seems a bit complicated. I will update my question with a simpler attempt i am trying at the moment.