# How to access a javascript object inside a string template?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with data and a string that works as a template, the purpose is to map the object's data into the string's variables. This is an example of my string:

```js
const menu = {
   breakfast: {
      description:'something' 
      }
   meal: {
      description: 'anotherSomething'
      }
}

const template = `<div>
   <ul>
     <li>
       %breakfast.description%
     </li>
     <li>
       %meal.description%
     </li>
   </ul>  
</div>
`
```

Obviously the simplest solution would be to create an array of the string variables and map the keys from my object, concatenate them and replace them like so:

```js
const myVariablesFromTemplate = ['breakfast.description', 'meal.description']
const myKeysToMap = {}
Object.keys(menu).forEach((item)=>{
    Object.keys(menu[item]).forEach((subItem)=>{
       const myNewKey = `${item}.${subItem}`
       myKeysToMap[myNewKey] = menu[item][subItem]
    })
  })

for(let key in myVariablesFromTemplate ){
  template.replace(key, myKeysToMap[key])
}
```

But I'm looking for a more elegant solution, where I could use javascript in the string dynamically and just access the object like in a template literal but I don't know if that's even possible. My method is not very robust, I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Why you don't use the interpolation feature of template literals?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression replacement with a function as the replacement, so it can look up the value in the the object.

```js
const menu = {
  breakfast: {
    description: 'something'
  },
  meal: {
    description: 'anotherSomething'
  }
}

const template = `<div>
   <ul>
     <li>
       %breakfast.description%
     </li>
     <li>
       %meal.description%
     </li>
   </ul>  
</div>
`

let result = template.replace(/%([^%]+)%/g, (g0, g1) => lookup(g1, menu));

console.log(result);

function lookup(path, obj) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((p, c) => p && p[c] || null, obj);
}
```

I got the `lookup()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43849204/1491895).

Comment: This is not bad, but for nested objects it might need a little more work.

Comment: @ManuelDuarte That's what the `lookup` function is for. It handles any level of nesting.

Comment: Just saw the complete answer on the other post, this is very good then. Didn't grasp the logic correctly at first. Amazing

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works in which I can replace my template variables with embedded template literals and then evaluate the whole template string as javascript. It's important to destructure the `myMenuInformation` object so the eval function has access to those values, otherwise it will return an error or undefined.
I used this question as reference alongside the mdn web docs:

[Can ES6 template literals be substituted at runtime (or reused)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused)

[MDN Web Docs Eval Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#:%7E:text=The%20eval()%20function%20evaluates,is%20parsed%20as%20a%20script.)

```js
function replaceVariables(myTemplate, myMenuInformation){
   const matchings = myTemplate.match(/(?<=\%)(.*?)(?=\%)/g);
    
        if (!matchings) {
          return myTemplate;
        }
        const originalMatchingText = matchings.map((m) => ({
          regexForReplacement: new RegExp('\\%' + m + '%', 'g'),
          templateLiteralVar: '${'+m+'}',
        }));
        
        let newBody = myTemplate;
        originalMatchingText.forEach((match) => {
          newBody = newBody.replace(
            match.regexForReplacement,
            match.templateLiteralVar,
          );
        });

        newBody = '`' + newBody + '`'
        var {breakfast, meal} = myMenuInformation
        return eval(newBody)
}

const mapped = replaceVariables(template, menu)
console.log(mapped)

// RESULT:
//<div>
//   <ul>
//     <li>
//     something
//     </li>
//     <li>
//       anotherSomething
//     </li>
//   </ul>  
//</div>
```