# ES6 How to process string interpolation if the function is returned after the string

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, string-interpolation

I have a function that returns an interpolated string for example.

```
`This is my string $t(some.value)`
```

The issue I am facing is that `t` is returned after I get the interpolated string. For example

```
const mainFunction = (targetString) => {
    
    const { t } = getTranslationService();

    return targetString;

}
```

I want to resolve the value and return the processed string in the mainFunction. I tried with `eval` but it didn't work

Comment: Which syntax rules do you have to indicate that a substring is to be evaluated?

Comment: what do you mean `t` is returned after you get the interpolated string, like `mainFunction` returns `targetString` and then sometime later `getTranslationService` returns `t` for you? Is `getTranslationService` like a network request/asyncronous?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @CotyEmbry, I will try to clarify that. The t is a function that I get asynchronously, but once it gets resolved, `t` can evaluate in a synchronous way. That makes sense?

Comment: @thank you for your comment @trincot, sorry I updated the question because I wrote it in the wrong way the first time. The interpolated string has the `$`, the parameter the function is getting is This is my string $t(some.value)

Comment: How will you know where the substring (that needs evaluation) ends? Like what if the string were `This is my string $1+t(some.value+1)+1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can ES6 template literals be substituted at runtime (or reused)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused)

Comment: @trincot thank you for your suggestion, I tried but it didn’t work. I found the answer I will post it in the question.

Comment: I don't know what you refer to when you say "I tried it". I didn't propose anything. On the contrary, I asked for clarifications because your question leaves doubt on some aspects. Also, if you have an answer, make sure *not* to post it in the question, but in the answer area.

Comment: thank you for the comment @Phil, this lead me a little bit to the answer I made some assumptions that were wrong.

Comment: Thank you @trincot I updated the question/answer to put it in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in case it is useful for someone else

My first assumption was wrong, the function `t` is async.

The second was it was more complex than I expected, I needed to create a `locale` folder with a file `en-US.json` since how it works and all these it is relying on i18n

Finally, the target string should be in the JSON file. the `t` function will call a key from the JSON file and the targetString (enclosed between curly braces) will be translated. All this works in an asynchronic way.

Answer (score -2):

you can do:

```js
`This is my string ${t(some.value)}`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: This isn't what OP wants