# JavaScript: late binding template strings

Tags: javascript

The following code does not work. It wants to bind the variable i
at the moment the line in backquotes is seen, and of course gets an error.

```
const template = `this is line ${i}`

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(template);
}
```

Desired output:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

You can see what I want: I want a late-binding template that will bind variables at the last possible moment. The example here is only a small simplification of what I really want to do, which involves an array of template strings one of which will be used.

Does JavaScript have a library for this sort of thing?

Comment: There is a special way that allows evaluating code when you want it, rather than when it's declared. No library needed. It's called "a function" - you write it, put the code you want in it, then it gets evaluated when you call it. You may think that such a powerful feature is long and cumbersome to use, yet look at this! ``templateFn = i => `this is line ${i}`;`` it is not much longer than the template itself!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003353/can-es6-template-literals-be-substituted-at-runtime-or-reused

Comment: Ah yes! I am more at home in Python, and in Python functions are substantial, and I would have used the % operator instead. But JavaScript functions are such lithe, light, limber little things, that they sneak up on me constantly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the template a function and call it inside the loop, you will get the desired output:

```js
const template = (i) => `this is line ${i}`

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(template(i));
}
```

> Does JavaScript have a library for this sort of thing?

Native JS only has string concatenation and template litterals, but there are tons of libraries which add sugar on top, such as [mustacheJS](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), [HandlebarsJS](https://handlebarsjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/), etc.