# I have a JSON response -> "You are on step {0} of {1}" How would I replace {0} and {1} with my values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

The serve returns a JSON object

```
{
 "key" : "Steps {0} of {1}"
}
```

How can I use {0} and {1} to replace with the values say "Steps 40 of 90" which I have in the front end object using javascript.

Comment: `.replace(/\{(\d+)}/, (m, $1) => obj[$1] || m)`

Comment: prob. dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975005/format-a-javascript-string-using-placeholders-and-an-object-of-substitutions

Comment: If {0} and {1} are fixed then you can use str.replace("{0}","value1"); and str.replace("{1}","value2"); Otherwise use regular expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a JavaScript string using placeholders and an object of substitutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975005/format-a-javascript-string-using-placeholders-and-an-object-of-substitutions)

Comment: Thanks but this does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: @Aatif How does this not work? What goes wrong if you try?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"key" : "Steps {0} of {1}"}');
var val1 = 40;
var val2 = 90;
var string = obj.key.replace('{0}', val1).replace('{1}', val2);
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you fetch value of **Key**.
You can use replace function like this.

```
var ans = str.replace("{0}","49(Your variable)")
```

It is normal string function.

Comment: Too much hard-coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the [JSON](http://json.org/) string and parse it, then replace with the suggested regular expression of [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) with a global flag and use an array for replacements of the numbers.

```js
var json = '{ "key": "Steps {0} of {1}" }',
    object = JSON.parse(json),
    replacements = [40, 90];

object.key = object.key.replace(/\{(\d+)}/g, (m, $1) => replacements[$1] || m);

console.log(object);
```

If you have no other replacements with the same numbers in the JSON string, you could replace the values directly in the string with

```js
var json = '{ "key": "Steps {0} of {1}" }',
    replacements = [40, 90];

json = json.replace(/\{(\d+)}/g, (m, $1) => replacements[$1] || m);

console.log(json);
```