# JavaScript Read data from multidimensional object with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, dynamic

### Background

I have an object like below:

```js
// Data from the database according to their columns and subordinate tables.
const itemData = {
    'license_number': '25/2022',
    'application': {
        'tracking_number': '535345345',
        'applicant_name': 'Misir Ali Humayun'
    }
};
```

I know I can read the data from this object like below:

```js
console.log(itemData.licese_number); // '25/2022'
console.log(itemData.application.tracking_number); // '535345345'

// or

console.log(itemData["licese_number"]); // '25/2022'
console.log(itemData.["application"]["tracking_number"]); // '535345345'
```

### Actual Issue

I want to read the data in a dynamic fashion. For example, I have a defined structure like below:

```js
var placeholder = [
    {
        "find": "%LICENSE%",
        "column": "license_number"
    },
    {
        "find": "%APPLICANT%",
        "column": "application.applicant_name"
    }
];
```

Now if I have a replacement function:

```js
const replacePlaceholdersWithData = (content) => {
    var replacements = {};

    // Constructing the object like { "%STRING%" : "DB_VALUE", "%STRING_2%" : "DB_VALUE_2" }
    placeholders.filter((object) => replacements[object.find] = itemData[object.column]); //  ISSUE HERE

    // @props https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975025/1743124
    content = content.replace(/%\w+%/g, function (all) {
        return replacements[all] || all;
    });

    return content;
};
```

...and a `content` like below:

```js
const content = "A License numbered %LICENSE% from the %APPLICANT% is received";
console.log(replacePlaceholdersWithData(content));

// Will output: 'A License numbered 25/2022 from the %APPLICANT% is received'
```

You can guess that the first placeholder (`%LICENSE%`) will be replaced with `'25/2022'`, but the second one won't be affected, because of the reading style at : `itemData["application.applicant_name"]` won't match with any real column/key.

QUESTION: **How can I resolve that issue?**

I know I can use `object.column.includes('.')` along with `object.column.split('.')` and get an array of dimensions. But I am clueless, how can I use the array to get data from a multi-dimensional object dynamically?

Comment: `object.column.split(".").reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], itemData)`. If you have possible nullish data in the nesting, use `acc?.[key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const itemData = {
    'license_number': '25/2022',
    'application': {
        'tracking_number': '535345345',
        'applicant_name': 'Misir Ali Humayun'
    }
};

const placeholder = [
  {
    "find": "%LICENSE%",
    "column": "license_number"
  },
  {
    "find": "%APPLICANT%",
    "column": "application.applicant_name"
  }
];

const content = "A License numbered %LICENSE% from the %APPLICANT% is received";

function replacePlaceholdersWithData(data, content) {
  placeholder.forEach(({find, column})=>content = content.replaceAll(find, lookup(data, column)))
  return content;
}
function lookup(data, path) {
  let [first, ...rest] = path.split('.');
  return rest.length ? lookup(data[first], rest.join('.')) : data[path];
}

console.log(replacePlaceholdersWithData(itemData, content));
```

Comment: Bulls Eye Andrew. Thank you so much. Solved a huge problem for me. 